# Is overwriting Lists while another Thread is reading Thread-Safe?

Tags: java, list, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a static List in my class, the content is loaded from a file whose content i get through an API endpoint. Along with the list i save a timestamp when the list was last refreshed or checked for updates.
This list is accessed by methods in the class, which are called from outside the class, but all methods **only read** from the list. The book object inside the List is also never altered, only read. Every time any method which accesses the list is called i check the timestamp, if it's older than a set frame i check the API for changes to the file. If changes to the file were made i start an async Thread realoading the file and once it's finished, i **overwrite** the list.

Now that got me wondering about Thread safety, since they are only reading i thought there should be no problems and i have not found any problems. But most of the methods accessing the list iterate over it, that got me wondering what happens when the reload of the list is saved while a method is iterating over it. Has it already made a copy at that point, or is it loading each entry per index?

I am aware, that the first person using a accessing method after the specified timeframe would get the old list, since the iteration will finish before the reload, this is fine.

```
private static List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
private static long timestamp = 0; 

static
{
    try
    {
        bookList = loadBookList();
        timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.error("Failed initial load of bookList : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}


public static String getShortFromName(String name) throws UnknownBookException
{
    asyncListCheck();

    for (Book book: bookList)
    {
        if (book.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name))
        {
            return book.getShort();
        }
    }

    throw new UnknownObjException(MSG_ERR_NOBOOK);
}

[...] More methods that access the list

private static void asyncListCheck() 
{
    new Thread(() ->
    {
        try
        {
            if (isOldList() && fileWasModified())
            {
                bookList = loadBookList();
                timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.error("Failed reload of bookList : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }).start();
}

public static List<Book> loadBookList() throws Exception
{
    // Make API call

    List<Object> objList = // Results end up in here
    
    List<Book> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Object obj: objList)
    {
        Map<String, Object> bookMap = (Map<String, Object>) obj;

        String name = String.valueOf(bookMap.get("name"));
        [...] more of this

        Book book = new Book();
        [...] set all the fields

        list.add(book);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Using Collections.synchronizedList(list) is not of use, since i only overwrite the whole list. I could instead empty the list and refill it, but that seems like unnecessary work?

Comment: We'd need to see all the code (including `loadObjList()`) but in general this will work once (because static initializations are made visible by the JVM) but any time you assign `objList` after that there's no memory visibility.  You should use, at minimum, the `volatile` keyword on that field, and depending on the rest of the code there certainly could be other problems.

Comment: @markspace I added the loadBookList() and replaced the MyObj with Book for readability. All the other methods that acces the list are doing something similar to getShortFromName(), just return a different field or a list of 1 field of all objects. The book object inside the List is also never altered, onyl read.

Comment: As long as no methods attempt to alter the list itself or its contents, Book, you should be OK with just using `volatile`.  Volatile has a full memory barrier, so any reads after the write of a volatile field will be correctly synchronized.  I don't really understand why you're using a thread in `asyncListCheck()`, and why you create a new thread each time you call `getShortFromName()` -- this is hugely inefficient.  But perhaps that is not pertinent to the question.

Comment: @markspace thanks for your help, volatile does seem like it would do enough after some research. There is no specific reason as to why asyncListCheck() creates a new thread each time, i'm inexperienced at multithreading and this was the easy solution that i came up with. While it does not belong to the original question, I'd be thankfor for advice or another method that i should research to make this more efficient.

Comment: This is not thread safe in a useful way. It may regenerate the list multiple times and re-use old lists longer than intended. It's much easier to fix this than to try to make arguments about eventual consistency based on the JMM.

Comment: @thatotherguy I'd love to hear your suggestions

Comment: The standard way would be a synchronized method that optionally updates and then returns the current book list. Consumers would then call that instead of accessing a field.

Comment: I'm assuming that the code above is just a [mcve] for the real code.  But a factory method is a nice idea.  Even if the field is private, encapsulating its functions in a method is always worth considering.  Saves copy paste and also puts all the code in one spot.